# Consuming webservice from application deployed on websphere

Tags: web-services, websphere, websphere-8

I have been trying to consume a webservice(WS-JAX) in java.
I have generated JAVA artifacts using wsimport tool. I constructed a standalone test class(on eclipse) and was able to call the webservice successfully. 
But when I use the same actifacts and code in my application(deployed on websphere 8) I get below exception 
`

```
  [2/5/16 10:54:13:531 MST]     FFDC Exception:java.lang.StackOverflowError SourceId:com.ibm.ejs.container.RemoteExceptionMappingStrategy.setUncheckedException ProbeId:200 Reporter:com.ibm.ejs.container.RemoteExceptionMappingStrategy@625fad44
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:367)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.DefinitionImpl.getAllServices(DefinitionImpl.java:859)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.DefinitionImpl.getAllServices(DefinitionImpl.java:873)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.util.WSDLWrapperReloadImpl.getAllServices(WSDLWrapperReloadImpl.java:903)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.util.WSDLDefinitionWrapper.getAllServices(WSDLDefinitionWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.wspolicy.wsdl.internal.subject.DefinitionSubjectProcessor.<init>(DefinitionSubjectProcessor.java:60)
    at com.ibm.wspolicy.wsdl.internal.WSDLProcessorImpl.buildWSDLPolicyModel(WSDLProcessorImpl.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.wspolicy.wsdl.WSDLProcessor.<init>(WSDLProcessor.java:137)
    at com.ibm.ws.wspolicy.policyset.WSDLHelperImpl.processWSPolicyInPackagedWSDL(WSDLHelperImpl.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deployment.WASAxis2PolicySetConfigurator.associatePolicySets(WASAxis2PolicySetConfigurator.java:385)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.client.WSClientConfigurationFactory.completeAxis2Configuration(WSClientConfigurationFactory.java:459)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.<init>(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.<init>(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:223)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.updateEndpointDescription(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:534)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.updateEndpoint(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.updateEndpoint(DescriptionFactory.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.getPort(ServiceDelegate.java:597)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.getPort(ServiceDelegate.java:513)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:99)`
```

Could someone shed some light on why the webservice call is failing when it is originating inside a application server?

Note: I have installed proper server certificates in the application server truststore.

Comment: can't help you much with just a stack trace to go off of.  Include relevant pieces of code and configuration in your question.  Also, that stack trace is clearly truncated (it will obviously be huge because it's a SOError) but make sure you are including relevant pieces of the stack as well.

Comment: You are right. The stack trace is huge. at `com.ibm.wsdl.DefinitionImpl.getAllServices(DefinitionImpl.java:873)` line is just printed more than 2000 times. I did not want to post everything.

Comment: Can you verify in adminconsole, if your WebService is installed correctly, to me it appears that the code is generated third-party tooling, can attach SystemOut.log along with your service name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found the solution, I had 2 different JRE's installed on my computer. One was from Oracle and the other was the jre bundled with websphere application server. For a application to be deployed on Websphere we have to generate the java artifacts using the IBM jre thats bundled with Websphere.

Thanks,
Harsha